# Orders of AR and MA models

Tags: arima, model-selection, seasonality, acf-pacf

I have a couple of ACFs and PACFs and cant seem to be sure about the order of AR(p) and MA(q).Can anybody kindly give me an insight into how to detect that?[image: TREND SERIES]

[image: SEASONAL SERIES]

Comment: Are you sure that the processes are stationary and there are no structural breaks? I think more context is necessary.

Comment: Can you include a plot of the series itself?